# Xamarin.Forms .NET Standard confusing references

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism, .net-standard-2.0

I've created two different Xamarin.Forms solutions from templates. The first one is created with Prism template pack (version 2.0.5) the other one is created with the built-in Xamarin template that comes with Visual Studio 2017 (15.5.0 Preview). Both solutions utilize .net standard 2.0 and build fine on all three platforms. Now to the confusing part. As seen in this image:

[image]

the Android-project references of the two solutions is quite different. Why don't the first project need all the references of that the second do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the Prism Template Pack is using the CopyNuGetImplementations feature of NuGet. This means that your projects do not need to add the references again.  They will automatically get any NuGet references you have added to the main XF project.  Much easier to manage.

Comment: Thank you! Just curious, where can i find the documentation of this (and maybe similar) featrues of nuget? Neither google or searching nuget.org yielded any documentation as result.

Comment: It's not really documented.  In fact, so many people were getting confused about this, I reverted the templates to require the Nugets be added to each project. It's just too new to start using.  I will wait until people get used to it first before adding it back into the templates.